# Android button don't work after animation

Tags: android, animation, layout, listener

I use animation in a button of my android application.The first pressing is working but after that the button doesn't work. I press it and it makes animation again but the listener don't work. Here is my code. How can I solve this?

```
private Animation anim

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.but_anim);

    Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
}


public void onClick(final View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){

        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //Some code...
            }
        });

        v.setAnimation(anim);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to change:
from:

```
v.setAnimation(ocrAnimation);
```

to:

```
v.startAnimation(ocrAnimation);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem. I tested it and it's working fine!